# Why is Opportunity not an option for insert using the Data Loader?

Tags: opportunity, data-loader

I am attempting to insert from a CSV a list of Opportunities, however, in the list of available Objects, opportunity is not one of them. I can insert OpportunityProduct or Opportunity Share, but not Opportunity.

Comment: Have you relabeled Opportunity? It's sorted alphabetically by label, not by object name.

Comment: @sfdcfox - Seems like that's the answer.